# Pass information for user athentication to XBAP application

Tags: c#, wpf, http, authentication, xbap

I want to pass information to athenticate a user to an XBAP application running in a browser. It's a username and password, where the password is hashed.

I've figured out how to do it via GET request (i.e. just pass in the information in a query string and use `BrowserInteropHelper.Source.Query` to get the information).

However that means exposing the data in the query string. Since the password is hashed it's not like you can actually *see* it, but it feels like bad practice to me. I can't find any real information about whether it's possible to pass data in via POST or a cookie. From what I've gathered from the internet cookies won't work for XBAP applications, but I might be wrong.

Does anyone know if and how it's possible to transfer this kind of data in a more secure way? It would also be nice to get a confirmation that cookies indeed won't work in this scenario - or how I need to go ahead and implement them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could gather from various sources on the internet, GET really is the only way to go in this scenario.

POST doesn't seem to work at all. Also, XBAPs cannot access any session cookies, so that option is not feasible as well.

(I would link to the sources, but it was more about collecting bits and pieces from everywhere and putting it together.)

We settled on passing the parameters via GET, but encrypting the whole query string. This is not an ideal solution, but it has to do until we have the resources to implement a more complex and prettier solution which enables sharing authentication details between two completely separate applications - where one is a Java application and the other an XBAP.